# *ngFor select a secondary option based on an index

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a ngFor with a t. which has a t.product and 4 price options `[t.price,t.price1,t,price2,t.price3]`

This all works great for the first t.price but I cant switch the price from t.price to t.price1 etc based on a radio button selection index 0 to 3. How can I select the t.price based on an index value?

tried to build an another array with only the correct price but that generate errors and does not update the price info at all in the ngFor loop.

```
<div id="mat-s" >
    <mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="ChkBtnSelection" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
      <mat-list-option dense *ngFor="let t of prodT" [value]="t.product" class="mat-list-item">  
        <div class="div_t">
          <p class="alignleft">{{t.product}}</p>
          <p class="alignright">  -- {{t.price | currency:'GBP'}}</p>
        </div> 
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

all works great but I can switch t.price to t.price2? the array has t.price to t.price3.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Only way I can think of doing this is: hide all and only show the one which has a array index set to true.

Comment: <p class="alignright" *ngIf="ProdT_P[0]">  -- {{t.price | currency:'GBP'}}</p>
          <p class="alignright" *ngIf="ProdT_P[1]">  -- {{t.price2 | currency:'GBP'}}</p>
          <p class="alignright" *ngIf="ProdT_P[2]">  -- {{t.price3 | currency:'GBP'}}</p>
          <p class="alignright" *ngIf="ProdT_P[3]">  -- {{t.price4 | currency:'GBP'}}</p>
          <p class="alignright" *ngIf="ProdT_P[4]">  -- {{t.price4 | currency:'GBP'}}</p>

Comment: Please add the code for your radio buttons. You could probably have the radio buttons select the right price directly as a value (not the index to the value) and the just bind to this selected price value.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of writing separate tags with structural directive *ngIf would work but is a little cumbersome. I don't see any good way of solving it in the view - but it would be easy to transfer it to the component

for example;

```
<mat-selection-list>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let t of prodT">
    ...
    <p>{{getPrice(t)}}</p>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

The getPrice method is called whenever the view is rendered, and provides the object with all the information you need. Then you can add any logic you like to return only the price you want from within your component method:

```
getPrice(product) {
  // some logic here to get price selected option...
  return price
}
```

I'm assuming here that you already have a reference in your component to the option you're talking about.

Comment: That's what I have done wanted a more elegant way of solving this.